# ubuntu mount nfs only if user is in group

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ldap, nfs, groups

I have basic-to-medium advanced network setup at my work.  We run an ubuntu 10.04 fileserver serving a few different directories (including /home) over NFS and all client machines (various ubuntu 10.04 to 11.04) authenticate through LDAP and mount these NFS shares.

as we get more and more interns coming through the door, I am getting more and more nervous about the security of my NFS shares, so I am looking for ways to reduce this.

One idea I had was instead of mounting all of my shares at start up through /etc/fstab, was mounting them at login and only mounting certain dirs based on the group the user is in.

so for example, if an intern logs in, it mounts /exports/users /exports/interns etc.  but if someone in accounting logs in, it mounts /exports/users /exports/accounting /exports/personel etc.   basically having 'sensitive' exports only mounted if the user is in the right group.

is this possible?   if so, how?  if not, any other suggestions to ease my (probably overly) paranoid soul?

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm. A quick 'n dirty approach would be to execute a script instead of a shell upon login. This script is supposed to check user's group and mount proper directories. After that execute a shell as normal.

How you do that ... depends on the way they connect. Is that  through ssh ?

Check the "User Rc file" on this link http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#74105